# Could not find default node or by name with 'com name' on node 'com name'?

Tags: 14.04, puppet

Manifest Directory Structure of sys_info module is like,

**Puppet**

- manifests (site.pp)
- modules - sys_info - manifests (init.pp)

**init.pp** is like,

```
class sys_info {
package { 'gkrelmm' :
     ensure => '2.3.5-5',
}
exec { 'gkrellm' :
     command => '/usr/bin/gkrellm &',
     require => Package['gkrellm'],
     }
}
```

and **site.pp** is like,

```
node 'losttemple.linuxmaster.com' {
      include sys_info
}
```

I've create these files and and typed on terminal

```
sudo puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp --modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules/
```

and it showed an error

```
Error: Could not find default node or by name with '(my com name)' on node (my com name)
```

Is there anything wrong with the code I typed?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're using puppet master / slave. This is a message from the puppet master when a node can't find it's definition in side.pp.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to puppet and I've got this issue too. From what I've learnt, I believe if you add a Node decoration with your puppet-master in [site.pp] the error will disappear.

After digging a bit, I understood that I was using puppet master/slave, and it means that the puppet master also applies what it finds in site.pp and this error occurs when it doesn't find its name there.